# URL string is not supported in windows phone web app

Tags: url, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am using Phonegap to develop windows phone webapp.
When I use query string in url the of page that Link does not working

code:

```
<a href="profile.html?id=10">Profile</a>
```

this link not working in windows phone 8.
Then how I can send value to another page.

Link working when query string is removed as bellow.

```
<a href="profile.html">Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using `#` insted of `?`.

Answer (score 1):

You can send value using local storage :-

```
    /* Page A */
window.localStorage.setItem("id", "stringValue");

/* Page B */
var stringValue = window.localStorage.getItem("id");
```

Option2 :-

You can use this jquery stuff too :- [**Using Jquery**](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler)